# wp_insert_post - How do I prevent incremental numbers on child pages?

Tags: urls, slug, wp-insert-post

I'm using `wp_insert_post` to dynamically generate child pages for a given page using a predefined array of values. The goal is to give each child page the same slug.

For example, clicking "Generate Pages" on "example-page" loops through `wp_insert_post` and creates two child pages:

```
/example-page/about
/example-page/contact
```

The trouble is that WordPress is adding numbers after the slug on the child pages (because similar child pages have already been created for a different page).

My guess is that it's doing a check on slug availability irrespective of the parent/child relationship.

I've experimented with trying to run `wp_update_post` after the insertion but to no avail.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here's a code sample:

```
$new_page = array(
    'post_title' => $child_page["title"],
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'post_name' => $child_page["slug"], 
    'post_content' => $child_page["content"],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'territory'
); 

$new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
```

Explanation: I am looping through an array of `$child_pages`, in which I've set the unique values for title, slug, and content.

Comment: show us the code you use to insert the child pages. do you explicitly set `post_name` and `post_parent`? the function responsible for uniqueness is [`wp_unique_post_slug`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug), but for child pages it only has to be unique within its branch, the function queries children of its parent for matching slugs.

Comment: I am explicitly declaring `post_name` and `post_parent`. I'll update with the code I'm using.

Comment: where is `$parent_id` set? are you sure that's a unique value each time you create the child pages? I ask because I do exactly this on a site and it works fine. you can test this manually- go to Pages in admin, create two top-level pages, then create a non-unique child page under each parent by first selecting the parent and then giving it the name. It will create identical child slugs under two different parent pages.

Comment: The `$parent_id` is unique. It's a function that is triggered via AJAX (you click a "Generate Pages" button). The ID is passed into the function and it does its job. Now, I can easily go back and *edit* the child slugs and remove the duplicates so it does work and, you're right, I can also do it manually.

Comment: Just as thought : is `territory` `post_type` hierarchical ?

Comment: Good question. Yes, it is. Always good to make sure :).

Comment: it's difficult to give you an answer without evaluating all of your code in context, since it's a *works for me* situation. I did something like this just yesterday with [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85827/automatically-create-child-pages-when-saving-a-parent-page/85832#85832) and it doesn't append numbers onto the slugs.

Comment: Ok, that was step #1.. I wanted to know if it *should* work. I noticed your code is not passing in `post_name`. Perhaps I should try *not* declaring it.

Answer (score 1):

This is about a year over due.

I have had a similar thing happen on my new word press install.
Creating pages dynamically and getting incremental numbers on the slug names.

During this process I realised that the original slug would access the last one.

ie. ../../dynammic-page would access ../../dynamic-page-4

The solution was in the trash folder! Wordpress maintains these old files. A new page of the same name and slug name will be assigned a slug with an increment.

I permanently deleted the trashed versions of the page and the newly created dynamic page was increment free. Hazzaar!

Hope that helps someone.

xK