# Automatically add another subpost of the same parent when a subpost is saved

Tags: wp-insert-post, children

I figured it out how to add one subpost when a post is saved. But now I need to know how I can get another subpost of the same parent when a subpost is saved. Could anybody help me out?

**This is what I have:**

//Subpage automatically created when Parent is saved

Parent 2014

- Subpage

**This is what I need:**

//NEW SUBPAGE is created when Subpage is saved

Parent 2014

- Subpage
- NEW SUBPAGE

Here is my current code (of what I have):
Source: [Automatically create child pages when saving a (parent) page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85827/automatically-create-child-pages-when-saving-a-parent-page/85832#85832)

```
// Automatically add one subpost when a post is saved
function wpa8582_add_show_children( $post_id ) {  
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )
    && 'show' == get_post_type( $post_id )
    && 'auto-draft' != get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {  
        $show = get_post( $post_id );
        if( 0 == $show->post_parent ){
            $children =& get_children(
                array(
                    'post_parent' => $post_id,
                    'post_type' => 'show'
                )
            );
            if( empty( $children ) ){
                $child = array(
                    'post_type' => 'show',
                    'post_title' => 'About',
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'draft',
                    'post_parent' => $post_id,
                    'post_author' => 1,
                    'tax_input' => array( 'your_tax_name' => array( 'term' ) )
                );
                wp_insert_post( $child );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpa8582_add_show_children' );
```

Comment: Where is your exact problem? So far I can only see that you have code that you say it works, but I can't see what you have tried and where you failed? Hint: Without the `empty( $children )` check you already should have what you want. Question: As I can read `'your_tax_name'`, I assume that you copy/pasted that from somewhere? From where exactly? Please file an [edit] and tell the source. Thanks.

Comment: When I remove the `empty( $children )`, there is another subpost added when I save the parent. When I am saving the subpost, there is currently nothing happening. I need to get it working when the subpage is saved (and not the parent).