# Custom routes for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, routing, wp-remote-request

I have a custom post type called 'event'. An event has multiple subpages like registration, speakers, contact us, etc. Currently the content is saved as one or more custom fields.

I would like to have an url structure like

- `events/{event_slug}/registration`
- `events/{event_slug}/speakers`
- `events/{event_slug}/contactus`

With each URL displaying the information from each custom field, respectively.

Is there a way, we can achieve this in WordPress?

Comment: You could make the "event" CPT hierarchical and make the details subpages instead of custom fields.

Comment: Yeah..thats true...but alreay I have many events with this setup.. Now I think need to search for a soultion this way only I guess..or do i have a way to switch back to subpages?

Comment: From my perspective it would be easier to sort out the data and go from there, than live with a suboptimal setup. You could write a script to pull the custom fields out into their own separate "event" cpt posts with the appropriate parent.

Comment: You can auto-create the child pages pulling their content from the custom fields on the parent page, using this type of function: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85832/16 You'd need to modify the $child array to pull in the correct fields via a meta_query.

Comment: Do not make subpages. Try using as query variable, ?v=registration or ?v=speakers. Using rewrite rules, you can make it a url. That being done, you can pull custom fields based on query variables by modifying Single event page.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this [resource](https://wpsmith.net/2019/custom-rewrite-rules-custom-post-types-taxonomies/). You can create own post types links (and probably relational template structure)

They said you can create `domain.com/{prefix}/{post-type-slug}/{postname}` like URLs with their code (Also you create even custom ones).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to enter an additional query variable and rewrite rule to set it. 
Meta fields will be displayed based on this new query variable.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'se353995_query_vars' );
add_action( 'init', 'se353995_sublinks', 20 );

function se353995_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = "subpage";
    return $vars;
}
function se353995_sublinks()
{
    $cpt_slug = 'events';
    $sublinks = '(registration|speakers|contactus)';

    add_rewrite_rule(
        "$cpt_slug/([^/]+)(?:/$sublinks)/?$",
        'index.php?'.$cpt_slug.'=$matches[1]&post_type='.$cpt_slug.'&subpage=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

An example of how to display the page, `single-events.php`:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    // check what event subpage to display
    $qv = get_query_var( 'subpage', false );
    if ( $qv == 'registration' )
    {
        // display "registration" subpage
        //
        $customfield_reg = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'meta_field_name', true) );
    }
    else if ( $qv == 'speakers' )
    {
        // display "child page" 
        //
        $customfield_reg = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'other_field_name', true) ;
    }
    else
    {
        // default one
        //
        get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );
    }

endwhile; // End of the loop.
```